# How to transpose a Hive table

Tags: hive, pivot

Could anyone help me understand, how to pivot an Hive table.

I have an Hive table like this :

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    Column C    Date        Price
A1          B1        C1          20171001    100
A1          B2        C2          20171001    50
A2          B2        C2          20171002    75
A3          B1        C2          20171002    10
```

I want to pivot the above table like this:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    Column C    20171001    20171002    Total
A1         B1         C1          100                     100
A1         B2         C2          50                      50
A2         B2         C1                       75         75
A3         B1         C2                       10         10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
select 
        ColumnA, 
        ColumnB, 
        ColumnC, 
        MAX ( CASE 
                WHEN Date_ = '20171001' 
                THEN Price 
        END ) price_20171001,
        MAX ( CASE 
                WHEN Date_ = '20171002' 
                THEN Price 
        END )      price_20171002 , 
        Max(Price) Total
FROM 
        Yourtable 
GROUP BY 
        ColumnA, 
        ColumnB, 
        ColumnC
ORDER BY 
        ColumnA;
```

**Note** : Since `Date` is an Invalid column , I have used `Date_`.